# Docker daemon fails to start

Tags: server, mount, services, docker

I have tried to move docker `/var/lib/docker` to `/data/lib/docker` on my ubuntu 18.04 server , and I changed `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` to :

```
FROM:
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd://
TO:
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -g /new/path/docker -H fd://
```

Now my containers and docker daemon fails to start even when I change the file back to previous one.

Is there any fix ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem resolved by restarting containerd service :

```
systemctl restart containerd
```

The problem came from when I changed systemd , containered daemon was affected , and without restarting the daemon , I could not restart docker service